# How can i use vue.js to adjust my side by an url input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Hello Stack Overflow community,
i'm a beginner who wants to create a web application with vue.js. It should be a one page application, which has a header and body. The header shows always the same content, but i want to change the content of the body when the user interacts.

It should work like this:
The page starts at www.mypage.com/home. Then the user presses a button and the content of the body shows something other and the url changes to something like www.mypage.com/contentOne, but the header doesn't change at all and the side shouldn't be reloaded. I saw a similar application with react.js, but i found nothing for vue.js.

Do i need a something like node.js or Ruby on Rails and if, is there a tutorial for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at vue-router
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

Comment: you can do it with vue... just make component that will always be there ... when u use  vue, for routing u usually use vue-router and with vue router u specify <router-view> and if u want some component always there just put it under or above router-view component

Answer (score 0):

Have you even searched? When you go to the "Get started" section on vuejs.org (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) there are excellent examples and tutorials, one of which is https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/vue-instance/
This will get you a long way creating what you describe above

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about Node.js or Ruby on Rails.

I'd recommend using the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to build your app, because it'll save you having to worry about all the config yourself. It'll come with `vue-router`, which will let you build a Single Page Application. Your header will go in the main `App.vue` file, and then you can load the body of the page into what's called the router view.

Have a look at the [Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/) which are really good and well-written.